# Is there a way to bypass or throw away a mouse event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if there was a way to "throw away", if that is the right term, or ignore a mouse event when it occurs.

For example,

Say I have a mouseenter bound to an object and I have a specific handler attached to it. Is there a way to ignore certain mouseenter events on that object so that the handler is not called during those instances?

Note: I realize you can do this with an 'if' statement but assume I do not have access to the handler function.

Comment: If you don't have access to the handler - can you detach the original handler and attach a new mouseenter-handler that wraps the original handler? This way you could fire the original handler by using the if-helpers in the answers below.

Comment: This sounds really complicated. What are you *actually* trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Just place an `if` inside the handler.

```
var fire = true;

$('#something').click(function() {
   if (!fire)
      return;
   // do fun stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use global "flag" for this.

For example, declare the global flag on top of your code like this:

```
var _ignoreMouseEnterOnce = false;
```

Now in your event handler have this:

```
if (_ignoreMouseEnterOnce) {
    _ignoreMouseEnterOnce = false;
    return;
}
```

And raise the flag wherever you want:

```
_ignoreMouseEnterOnce = true;
```

Comment: check the note in the question